# В указанный в Вашем запросе период С.А. Петров упоминался в

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые в следующей конструкции -  и где

В указанный в Вашем запросе период С.А. Петров упоминался в...

Answer (score 3):

Здесь нет знаков препинания.

Для обособления оборота "В указанный в Вашем запросе период" нет никаких оснований.

Кроме того, причастный оборот перед определяемым существительным не обособляется, поэтому не нужна запятая и перед словом "перед".

Comment: да Vera, вы что-то не о том, написали. Или это происки незваного "редактора"?

Comment: Понял, откатил. Сейчас поправлю. Vera, пишите подробнее. А то есть желание все понять не так.

Comment: Вера, еще совет. Цитируйте текст вопроса в том виде, как он задан исходно или тот на который отвечаете. Тогда и недоразумений не будет из-за последующей правки.

Answer (score 2):

Определение, выраженное причастным оборотом и стоящее перед определяемым словом, не обособляется.

P.S. Niemand прав: автор спрашивает о другом. Запятая не нужна.

Comment: Tangrix, автор не спрашивает о другом. Это господин Демин переделал все на свой вкус. Проверяйте исходный текст вопроса после неавторской правки, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

"Причастный оборот перед определяемым словом" тут ни при чем! Автор спрашивает о запятой *после* слова "период", а не *перед* ним. Запятая не нужна.

Comment: Ниманд, а вы кому отвечаете-то?

Comment: angrix, автор не спрашивает о запятой ни до ни после. Это господин Демин переделал все на свой вкус. Проверяйте исходный текст вопроса после неавторской правки, пожалуйста. Я уже устал с этим бороться.